# Animation inside a .obj file?

Tags: unity, 3d, animation, models

Ok, so yesterday I understood that "rigging (bone and joints)" are things that are use inside a 3D animation software like maya. By that I mean that those bones and joints are not inside the .obj file but only inside the software to help you animate the model.

My plan was to create my own voxel model using my own editor, then load it up into maya to animate it and then put it inside Unity to use the animation but from what I understand, its impossible to put multiple frame inside a file to use the pre-made animation inside a software like Unity.

Does that mean that I will have to load my voxel model inside unity and animate it using the Unity Animation Engine ?

Answer (score 1):

Its true that .obj files contain only “one frame“. You could try a different file format like md5. It should be supported by many 3D modeling programs and it is also a text based file like the obj.

Comment: Yeah, so I will need to animate using Unity itself ?

Comment: Alternatively, `dae` and `fbx` are the most commonly supported, industry-standard model formats which include animation data. You can use any program which is capable of exporting to those formats to do the rigging (Maya, 3DS Max, Blender, Modo, etc.). Most of these support `md5` as well.

Comment: When you are exporting a model with an animation, you must load the model with the animation, no need to animate in unity.